# Get full compilation command in CMake

Tags: c, cmake

If you execute `vim --version`, it will show some information about how it was compiled. On my system, it looks like this:

> Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
>
> Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype  -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -lncurses -lelf -lnsl   -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic   -lruby -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib
>   ```

I want to add similar information to the version output of an application that is built using CMake.

I know that there are variables like `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`, but it depends on other variables if these are actually used. For example, `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` is used if `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` is specified. Thus it might be error-prone to try to piece this information together from individual CMake variables, and in the end you can't be sure that this is really what CMake uses to compile your sources.

Is there a way to get the actual command CMake uses to compile a source file, similar to the output from `vim --version` above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moreover, `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` could vary for different source files, directories and targets… so your output can be far from accurate…

and using variables like `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is pretty stable actually and may give you what you want:

```
string(TOUPPER "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" _type_upcase)
# Yeah! CMake can do double expand!
set(_cflags "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${_type_upcase}}")
```

little problem is: make sure `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is set and valid before get the value!

advanced way:
one may use `CMAKE_<lang>_COMPILE_OBJECT` variable to get a "compile template". then use directory properties to collect `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` and replace a pattern `<DEFINES>` in the template. then collect `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and other options depending on build type.
You may look [here](https://github.com/mutanabbi/chewy-cmake-rep/blob/master/AddCompileTests.cmake) for inspiration.